# Next.js PDFtron Webviewer - ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-dom, pdftron

I'm trying to create a PDF viewer on my nextjs static page but i dont know how! hope you guys can help me solving this error or showing one other way to do this. (I'm new to Next.js) I was following this working example [here](https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-react-sample/blob/master/src/App.js)

index.js

```
import SiteLayout from "../../components/SiteLayout";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Viewer from "../resume/viewer.js";

export default function Resume({ resume }) {
  return (   
    <div>
      <Viewer />
    </div> 
  );
}
```

viewer.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import WebViewer from "@pdftron/webviewer";

const Viewer = (props) => {
  const viewer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {       
    WebViewer({
      path: "/lib",
      initialDoc: "/pdf/GustavoMorilla.pdf"
    }, viewer.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Viewer">
      <div className="header">React sample</div>
      <div className="webviewer" ref={viewer}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Viewer;
```

Comment: Where are you rendering Resume? You are getting the error because of this ReactDOM.render(<Viewer />)

Comment: for a Navbar item "resume" the user will be redirected to this page via "href" ... I need a way to load the page and call the Viewer component that contains the webviewer. Dont know if this react DOM declaration is correct.

Comment: Why do you use ReactDOM.render(<Viewer /> instead of <Viewer/>?

Comment: Are you missing to pass viewer.current as second argument in WebViewer function?

Comment: Try to add more details about the error (line, file, etc) because I don't see anything wrong

Comment: ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gustavo Morilla\MyProfile\node_modules\@pdftron\webviewer\webviewer.min.js:1:224)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14).....

Comment: I think that just importing the function is causing the error, the solution will be to import the function inside useEffect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebViewer` needs the `window` object to work.
In `nextjs` there is a prerender phase server side and on that side `window` is not defined.

To solve your problem you can use [next/dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#basic-usage) in `viewer.js`

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const WebViewer = dynamic(() => import('@pdftron/webviewer'), {ssr: false});
```

Alternatively you can import `Viewer` in `index.js` with dynamic import

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Viewer = dynamic(() => import('../resume/viewer.js'), {ssr: false});
```

Comment: But useEffect will runs in client side, not server side, and he is calling WebViewer inside useEffect, or just importing the function will causes some code runs

Comment: The import (and ssr) is at component level. I see the same error many times in nextjs applications and the response Is always the same :)

Comment: Thanks dna! my code finally works fine. I never used the dynamic imports before and now i see one environment where its necessary. Its simple but thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

When you import `@pdftron/webviewer` some code is running even though you haven't called the `WebViewer` function. The useEffect callback doesn't run in SSR. You can use [Dynamic Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) there to import the module:

```
useEffect(() => {    
    import('@pdftron/webviewer')
     .then(WebViewer) => {
        WebViewer({
          path: "/lib",
          initialDoc: "/pdf/GustavoMorilla.pdf"
        }, viewer.current);
    }) 
}, []);
```

Comment: I admire your follow-up and attention lissettdm, the answer from dna worked!

Comment: Yes, I wanted to share a native solution without extra lib, also you can use 'require' if you don't want to use dynamic module, but if you are using nextjs the answer from @dna is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting 'window is not defined', the only solution that worked for me was following the [NextJs way](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-external-libraries) for importing external libraries dynamically:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const loadWebViewer = async () => {
    const WebViewer = (await import('@pdftron/webviewer')).default;
    if (viewer.current) {
      WebViewer(
        {
          path: '/lib',
          initialDoc: `/api/getPdf/${encodeURIComponent(file)}/`,
          disabledElements: [
            'viewControlsButton',
            'viewControlsOverlay',
            'toolsOverlay',
            'ribbonsDropdown',
            'selectToolButton',
            'panToolButton',
            'leftPanelButton',
            'toggleNotesButton',
            'toolsHeader',
          ],
        },
        viewer.current
      );
    }
  };
  loadWebViewer();
}, []);
```